# How to use --dart-define in a Flutter app embdedded in Android

Tags: flutter

I'm Embedding a Flutter app as a module within an existing Android app (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) and would like to know if/how I can use "--dart-define" to define compile-time constants.  Tried using `./gradlew -Ddart-define=myVal=Value` without any luck.

When building a typical Flutter app I would use the `flutter` command.  In my case I'm continuing to use `gradlew` to build my app and it's unclear how to pass in --dart-define constants.

Comment: `flutter run --dart-define=myVal=Value` and `flutter build --dart-define=myVal=Value` work with "normal" flutter mobile apps... but when I'm embedding a Flutter module within an existing Android app I continue to use gradle to build the app... Was looking for a way to add "dart-define" to the gradle command so that the embedded Flutter app will have it available at runtime.

Answer (score 9):

[image: configuration]

In android studio you may edit running configuration (press drop-down near "run" button -> "Edit configurations...") and define variables there ("Additional run args:" row):

```
--dart-define="http_serv=http://10.0.2.2:42627/" --dart-define="websocket=ws://10.0.2.2:42627/websocket"
```

Getting variable in code:

```
const checkArgs = String.fromEnvironment('http_serv', defaultValue: '');
```

Comment: Make sure to use the `const` keyword in the variable declaration, otherwise it'll [silently] fall back to the defaultValue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870#issuecomment-620779475

Answer (score 3):

**If your project depends on the Android Archive (AAR).**

You can pass the `dart-defines` in the command line.

`flutter build aar --dart-define=myVal=Value`

**If your project depends on the module’s source code.**

You can set `dart-define`s in `gradle.properties` in your android host project directory （or in `yourHostProject/yourFlutter/.android/Flutter/` directory）.

```
--dart-define=myVal=Value
```

**Explanation**

- `.android/Flutter/build.gradle` script executes `"$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"` script. When the `flutter.gradle` is executed, your dart files are compiled into naitive code.
- `flutter.gradle` loads dart-defines from the `.android/Flutter` project instance （[flutter.gradle#731-L734](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c99f60b82f03db3c4a6cfee2a53ffb73e53ab431/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#L731-L734)) and then, use it ( [flutter.gradle#L1091-L1093](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c99f60b82f03db3c4a6cfee2a53ffb73e53ab431/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#L1091-L1093)).
- To set the project instance value, you add `--dart-define=myVal=Value` into `gradle.properties`. (If you have  multiple `gradle.properties` files, consider configuration order（[Gradle properties in Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)).

Comment: How do we pass this dart-define as an argument from Android app rather than setting this in flutter project's gradle.properties file? For instance if I need to set a different API secret key based on product flavor we choose in android app? how do we do that?
@SShayashi

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your properties at:

```
YourProject/android/gradle.properties
```

as so:

```
dart-defines=cmVxdWVzdExvZ2dlcj10cnVl,dGFsa2VyTG9nZ2VyPXRydWU=
```

Where the values are base64 encoded and comma separated.

*Example gradle.properties file:*

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
dart-defines=cmVxdWVzdExvZ2dlcj10cnVl,dGFsa2VyTG9nZ2VyPXRydWU=
```